# Plotting contour lines that show percentage of particles

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, contour

What I am trying to produce is something similar to this plot:

[image]

Which is a contour plot representing 68%, 95%, 99.7% of the particles comprised in two data sets.

So far, I have tried to implement a gaussain KDE estimate, and plotting those particles gaussians on a contour.

Files are added here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/86r9hf61wlzitvy/AABG2mbmmeokIiqXsZ8P76Swa?dl=0

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# My data
x = RelDist
y = RadVel

# Peform the kernel density estimate
k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([RelDist, RadVel]))
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()


CS = ax.contour(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), colors='darkslateblue')
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)

ax.set_xlim(20, 800)
ax.set_ylim(-450, 450)
ax.set_xscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Producing this:

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Cqx.png)

Where 1) I do not know how to necessarily control the bin number in gaussain kde, 2) The contour labels are all zero, 3) I have no clue on determining the percentiles.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have any sample data to reproduce your plot?

Comment: @Tkanno I have added it

Comment: leads to a broken dropbox  link @DarthLazar

Comment: Mea culpa, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

taken from this [example in the matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) documentation

you can transform your data zi to a percentage scale (0-1) and then contour plot.

You can also manually determine the levels of the countour plot when you call plt.contour().

Below is an example with 2 randomly generated normal bivariate distributions:

```
delta = 0.025
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10* (Z1- Z2)

#transform zi to a 0-1 range
Z = Z = (Z - Z.min())/(Z.max() - Z.min())

levels =  [0.68, 0.95, 0.997] 
origin = 'lower'
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels,
              colors=('k',),
              linewidths=(3,),
              origin=origin)

plt.clabel(CS, fmt='%2.3f', colors='b', fontsize=14)
```

[image]

Using the data you provided the code works just as well:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

RadVel = np.loadtxt('RadVel.txt')
RelDist = np.loadtxt('RelDist.txt')
x = RelDist
y = RadVel

k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([RelDist, RadVel]))
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

#set zi to 0-1 scale
zi = (zi-zi.min())/(zi.max() - zi.min())
zi =zi.reshape(xi.shape)

#set up plot
origin = 'lower'
levels = [0,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.68, 0.95, 0.975,1]

CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi,levels = levels,
              colors=('k',),
              linewidths=(1,),
              origin=origin)

plt.clabel(CS, fmt='%.3f', colors='b', fontsize=8)
plt.gca()
plt.xlim(10,1000)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylim(-200,200)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Tkanno is programmatically correct but does not do exactly what was asked in the question.

The kde returns the likelihood of a sample according to the modeled distribution. The contour plots are therefore limits on the probability of a sample. The 0.1 contour plot would show the limit beyond which samples have less than 10% of chance to appear according to the modeled distribution. Now by normalising the z value as proposed by Tkanno, it is now relative probabilities that are plotted so in Tkanno's answer the 0.1 contour plot is the limit beyond which samples are 10 times less likely to appear than the most likely sample.

You could very similar contour plots as proposed by Tkanno (yet not smoothed) by doing a 2d-histogram, normalizing by the most frequent bin and plotting the contours with same levels.

This is not to be assimilated with a limit containing 90% of the data.
I think contour plots that encompass given fraction of the data are a bit more complicated to get (cf https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68105/contours-containing-a-given-fraction-of-x-y-points and the solution with bag plots).
Apparently there is an implementation of bag plots in R, maybe someone has/will make it for python.

To illustrate the difficulty of solving the question, one can think of a dataset with 100 points. Any volume containing 95 points, excluding 5 would actually answer the question. What is probably implicitly asked is the smallest volume containing 95 points (hence representing the highest likelyhood or density), and this is a combinatorial optimisation problem.