# Contour plot from xy data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour

I want to plot contour lines for 2D data (xy) representing 68%, 95%, 99.7% of the data. My question is almost similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784187/plotting-contour-lines-that-show-percentage-of-particles) but I do not have Z-axis values. Is there any possibility to do it in python ?.

EDIT: From the reference question, I have applied the same code for my problem. (This is half code)

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = X_data
y = Y_data

k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([X_data, Y_data]))
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

#set zi to 0-1 scale
zi = (zi-zi.min())/(zi.max() - zi.min())
zi =zi.reshape(xi.shape)
plt.plot(X_data, Y_data, 'bo', ms =1)
#set up plot
origin = 'lower'
levels = [0,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.68, 0.95, 0.975,1]

CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi,levels = levels,
          colors=('k',),
          linewidths=(3,),
          origin=origin)

plt.clabel(CS, fmt='%.3f', colors='b', fontsize=8)
plt.xlabel(r'$X_{data} [V]$', fontsize=fontall)
plt.ylabel(r'$Y_{data} [A]$', fontsize=fontall)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

and I got this figure:
[image: Output]

I want to understand is this the correct result ?. I want to see the contour levels that represent 68%, 95% and 99.7% of my data.

Comment: Can you please add a picture of the result you are looking for?

Comment: I have added code and image in the main question

Comment: Try to add some alpha to your datapoints plot.  `plt.plot(X_data, Y_data, 'bo', ms=1, alpha=.4)`  See of those lines show thru more.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Thank you for the tip. But I couldn't understand whether my code is actually representing the different density levels (confidence intervals) for 68%, 95% and 99% for the data. As per my understanding, each contour level represents the data that has same height and it doesn't give information regarding the density of the data or confidence interval. Is there any possibility to calculate the confidence intervals from contour lines or kde ?.

Comment: @frasheed I used your code and plotted few points and I think the contour lines we labelled.

Comment: @ScottBoston: The contour lines are labelled but do they actually represent density of the data?. Can I define that the contour level 0.05 represents the 95% of the data?. I am confused with the density because contour lines represents levels not density.